# Kubernetes with Kops is it correct to have each master in its own instance group?

Tags: kubernetes, kops

When I create a Kubernetes cluster and specify the `--master-zone us-west-2a,us-west2b-us-west2c` I end up with 3 masters (which is fine) but they are in different instance groups.

i.e.

```
$ kops get ig 
Using cluster from kubectl context: kube2.mydomain.net

NAME            ROLE    MACHINETYPE MIN MAX ZONES
master-us-west-2a   Master  m4.large    1   1   us-west-2a
master-us-west-2b   Master  m4.large    1   1   us-west-2b
master-us-west-2c   Master  m4.large    1   1   us-west-2c
nodes           Node    m4.large    3   3   us-west-2a,us-west-2b,us-west-2c
```

I'm not sure this is correct, or is this a best practice?

I would think that all the masters should be in one instance group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean multiple availability zones. This is the default behavior for redundancy. Cloud providers like AWS recommend spreading your control plane (and your workloads for that matter) among different availability zones.

If you want to create them in a single zone you can run something like this, for example:

```
$ kops create cluster --zones=us-east-1c --master-count=3 k8s.example.com
```

Or

```
$ kops create cluster --zones=us-east-1b,us-east-1c --master-zones=us-east-1c --master-count=3
```

More info [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/issues/732).

I believe the rationale behind having an instance group (that map to ASGs in AWS) is that if you specify multiple availability zones in an ASG there are no guarantees that the nodes will land in a way that there is one on each availability zone.

Comment: Well I do want them across 3 AZ's but I also want them to be part of the same instance group.  Similar to regular nodes. Regular nodes are distributed across 3 AZ's but they are all part of the same instance group. `--masters=3` makes three instance groups with 1 machine per instance group which seems wrong to me 

 ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Are you talking about autoscaling groups?

Comment: no, instance groups, i.e. `kops  get ig nodes` <- that is the command to get the Instance Group. I want all the masters in the same instance group but on different AWS Availability Zones. Kops does this with the nodes by default, not sure whu it does not do this with the masters. Instead it creates 3 instance groups for the masters. It's odd how it does this.

Comment: Ohh I see, so instance groups map to autoscaling groups in AWS. What's the issue with having an ASG for each master. The issue is that if you specify multiple av zones in an ASG there are no guarantees that the nodes will land in a way that there's one on each av zone.

Comment: that is what I concluded in the end and kept it as is. I am running kiam server on the masters and this issue arose from having to use nodeSelector across all the masters. I prob should not use the masters as kiam server hosts but that is how I got to this question.